# Converting map keys of type array to a 2D slice

Tags: dictionary, go, set, slice

I've created a Set of array of int (to keep unique triplets) and after doing some steps need to return the list of triplets. Following snippet shows only the part that is trying to do this conversion and something is going wrong there. The resulted 2D Slice is getting triplets duplicated.
Please help me with following:

1. What is the problem with following code?
2. What should be the correct way to do this conversion?

Try [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/L2Y1w6UD9jr)

```
func main() {
    setOfTriplets := make(map[[3]int]struct{})

    // Oversimplified steps here just to show some usage of the setOfTriplets.
    t1, t2 := [3]int{1, 2, 3}, [3]int{4, 5, 6}
    setOfTriplets[t1] = struct{}{}
    setOfTriplets[t2] = struct{}{}

    // Convert the triplets to 2D slice (because that's what I need in the bigger problem)
    matrix := make([][]int, 0, len(setOfTriplets))

    for t, _ := range setOfTriplets {
        // array to slice
        st := t[:]

        // PROBLEM: Something unkown happening here.
        matrix = append(matrix, st)
    }

    // PROBLEM:
    // Expected Output: [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
    // Actual Output:   [[1 2 3] [1 2 3]] and sometimes [[4 5 6] [4 5 6]]
    fmt.Println(matrix)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the loop variable to create a slice. The loop variable is an array that is overwritten for each iteration. During the first iteration, if the tiplet is [1,2,3], this gets copied to `t` and a slice is created from this. Next iteration will overwrite `t` with `[4,5,6]`, which will also overwrite the triplet you added to the list before.

To fix, create a copy of the array:

```
   for t, _ := range setOfTriplets {
        t:=t // Copy the array
        // array to slice
        st := t[:]
        matrix = append(matrix, st)
    }
```